# Beamer: how to show picture after itemize?

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

Suppose I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Hello
\item<2-> World
\item<3-> !
\end{itemize}
\pause
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{smallcat.jpg}
    \caption{Smallcat}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code is suppose to show: hello -> world -> exclamation mark, then show a picture of a small cat.

However, for reason unknown, the picture of the cat shows up on the second pause in the itemize block.

[image]

How do I make the cat show up after the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\pause` command works independently from the items, so it shows the figure starting from the second slide. To show it starting from the fourth one you could add another two `\pause`s. But I'd suggest to use something like `\uncover` to make the code more readable:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Hello
\item<2-> World
\item<3-> !
\end{itemize}
\uncover<4->{%
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{smallcat.jpg}
    \caption{Smallcat}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, why is the % necessary after \uncover?

Comment: @DetectiveMooch https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: @DetectiveMooch: In this case it isn't, but sometimes you'd get spurious spaces in the compiled PDF without such `%` signs. And read what samcarter showed you for a detailed explanation.